# How can I get the value from v-select using a name attribute whilst using vuetify

Tags: laravel, vue.js

While using v-text-field on vuetify I am able to use the name attribute and capture the form input. However, a name attribute on v-select doesn't seem to work. I am currently using Vuetify for theming only within a laravel application and do not want to reach into using v-model. Is there a way to work around this so I can get the form value from v-select.

```
<v-select name="parent_id" 
    :items="{{ json_encode($entries) }}" 
    label="Select Parent" {{ !$errors->has('parent_id') ?'': 'error' }}
    hint="{{ $errors->has('parent_id') ? $errors->first('parent_id') :"" }}" persistent-hint="">
</v-select>
```

For brevity, ive not included the v-text-field options. However on the backend I am able to obtain everything other than parent_id as shown.

[image: dump on request]

Comment: show your code dude

Comment: Can you not use v-model?

Comment: As indicated, I do not want to reach for v-model since the form is in a blade template and I see no need for javascript code yet. I am using vuetify mainly for theming.

Comment: You could create a hidden input that has the same `v-model` as your `v-select` with a name, and thus it will send it on form submit.

Comment: Thanks Neat. But I figured there must be a better or a default way to do it. Since this will mean that Ill have to create two fields for every select I have. Seems redundant.

Comment: @FrancisKisiara, if you really don't want to add any of your own javascript, I think Neat's suggestion is the way to do it. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any prop for the v-select that would affect its input element's name attribute.

Answer (score 0):

v-select component has two props one for display and other for value
item-value , item-text
if we has

```
items =[
{id:1,name:'hi'}
];
```

we can use  `<v-select :items="items" item-value="id" item-text="name" />`